# PayPal-Cordova-Plugin not working / deprecated

Tags: cordova, paypal

Does anyone know how to fix this?

It seems like the image is on top of the text.

Plugin url: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

I've been through the whole plugin source and cannot find anything or any CSS to position the options.

[image: Plugin Issue]

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a deprecated integration based on an old PayPal mobile SDK that is no longer supported. You should not use it.

Comment: Any alternative suggestion to integrate PayPal in Cordova?